# Effective download management between server and app

Tags: android, api, download

I have a web api and an android / iOS app. The apps have to download files from the web api for offline access. These files range from a couple of MB to 400MB - they're .zip files containing HTML5 content.

At the moment, when a download is interrupted (connection drops), the download fails. I want to implement a way to save the downloads progress so that it can be paused (or if the connection drops) and resumed later.

Is this something that is standardised? (should I be googling certain terms?) or is there plug'n'play open source libraries that handle this for me? Is this something that is mainly handled by my API server? or by my apps?

Any help in directing my research is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's worth noting that this is not just a client decision. Your server so the same should support restoration the download.

I searched "android download manager library restoration download" and find next libs:

- [Android-Download-Manager-Pro](https://github.com/majidgolshadi/Android-Download-Manager-Pro)
- [koush/ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)

But I think it cost you to split your file [into multiple smaller files](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/86/) (split zip arry). And unpack the device. Then you can simply restart the parts that are not loaded and not try to reestablish the download.